# How can I share code between different domain names in Rails 3.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, multi-tenant

I have a directory of physicians already working with Rails 3.1 and mysql. Physicians can register and then add their doctors practice into the database. I now need to put other directories online under different domain names. So, let's say I already have a running website on e.g.

www.cardiology.com (with lists of cardiologists, seperated by city in one country)

Now I need other websites with other kind of doctors, e.g.:

www.oncology.com
www.dermatology.com
etc...

All these websites have the same basic structure, the same cities in the same country in which the doctors are listed. Just the texts of the websites and of cause the list of doctors is different. But they all have their own domain name. Since I need to update the code on a regulary base I don't want to update each code seperatly. It would be the best if I have one common base of code and just seperate the content.

Does anybody knows the best way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating an Engine of the core items and then building individual apps on top of that. An Engine is like a Gem only for complete Rails apps.

[Railscast on Engines (dated)](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/)

[A guide to starting your own engine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/)

[API Doc](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html)